# Magento 2: Custom Module URL Key Magento Function

Tags: magento2, module, url, custom, save

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0.

I'm creating a custom module. For saving data I'm using custom INSERT query.

In that INSERT query, i also need to save URL Key/Identifier which is going to display on Browser URL while user access.

URL Key will be a replica of Post Title. Title Contains Example: Hi Can't Save Dat``a.

```
if (empty($model->getData('url_key'))) {
    $urlKey = str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($model->getData('url_key')));
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `post` (`title`, `url_key`) VALUES ('" . $model->getData('title') . "', '" . $urlKey . "');";
$connection->query($sql);
```

In URL Key, we have `, `` or any the characters. What can I use as a function, which Magento uses to store product's URL Key in my Custom Module?

So I don't have to write multiple `str_replace` functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what magento uses internally, but since you are writing insert sql i think you will be fine with any general function. For example this helper function:

```
protected function _clean($str, $replace = array(), $delimiter = '-')
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
    if (!empty($replace)) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;

}
```